# Understanding hyperplanes as a set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I was asked to prove that a subset

$H = \{(x_1,...,x_n) \in\Bbb{F}^n|a_1x_1 + a_2x_2...+a_nx_n = 0\}$

of $F^n$ is a hyperplane if and only if $a_i \neq 0$ for some $\mathit{i}$

When trying to prove this I understand that at least one $a_i$ has to be nonzero since if every $a_i$ were zero then any vector in the space would satisfy, thus making H not a hyperplane, but I don't really understand the intuition besides that going either way. Please help.

Comment: We can write this using column vectors as $a^Tx=0$ with $a^T$ the transpose of $a$ so that $H$ is the set of vectors orthogonal to $a$. can you figure it out from there?

Comment: we haven't learned the concept of orthogonality yet.

Comment: How are you defining the hyperplane without orthogonality?

Comment: a subspace of V with dimension n-1

Comment: From a geometric standpoint a hyperplane is the subspace orthogonal to a single vector. For example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ if I choose a vector then the space orthogonal to it will be a plane through the origin and has dimension $3-1=2$ and this example is what gives the hyperplane the "plane" portion of its name. Using this idea, try showing vectors of the form $\lambda a$ for scalar $\lambda$ and the non-zero vector $a$ are the only vectors in $\mathbb{F}^n$ not in $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically you can think of $H$ as consisting of the vectors $\vec{x}=(x_i)$ that are perpendicular to some given non-zero vector $\vec a = (a_i)$ i.e. such that $\vec x . \vec a = 0$.

Algebraically, to show that $H$ is a hyperplane, you have to show two things:

i) $H$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$ - this is clear because if $\vec x . \vec a =0$ and $\vec y . \vec a = 0$ then $(\vec x + \vec y).\vec a = 0$.

ii) The dimension of $H$ is $n-1$. One way to show this is to pick one of the $a_i$ that is non-zero (we know there is at least one) - let's say this is $a_n$. Then if we set $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}$ to any values we like, there is exactly one value of $x_n$ that will satisfy $\vec x . \vec a = 0$ - that value is

$x_n = \displaystyle -\frac { \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_jx_j }{a_n}$

So we have $n-1$ degrees of freedom when choosing an element of $H$, and so $H$ has dimension $n-1$.

An alternative but equivalent approach is to show that the $n-1$ vectors

$b_1 = (1,0,0,\dots,0,-\frac{a_1}{a_n}) \\
b_2 = (0,1,0,\dots,0,-\frac{a_2}{a_n}) \\
\dots \\
b_{n-1} = (0,0,0,\dots,1,-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n})$

form a basis for $H$.

Comment: Good answer for giving both the geometric intuition (in terms of perpendicularity, as well as degrees of freedom) and a simple enough proof.